# How to get a generic MethodInfo with Type.GetMethod(string name, int genericParameterCount, Type[] types)?

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.1

I am trying to get the `MethodInfo` of the specific method `Interlocked.CompareExchange<T>(ref T, T, T)` and tried the below code to no avail:

```
typeof(Interlocked).GetMethod(nameof(Interlocked.CompareExchange), 1, new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int) })
```

Note that `typeof(int)` is just a random type. All I need is the `MethodInfo` so that I can later use `GetGenericMethodDefinition` with different types.

What array of types should we pass to get the required method?

Comment: [Is this what you are looking for?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netstandard-2.1#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Int32_System_Type___)

Comment: @Sweeper indeed it seems i missed it, but how do we call the method when reflecting something like `MyMethod<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)`? What do we provide in Type[]?

Comment: What do you want `T1` and `T2` to be?

Comment: 'What do we provide in Type[]?' -> an array containing the types T1 and T2, in the same order.

Comment: They could be anything, i just need to get the MethodInfo of MyMethod. What am trying to do is get the overload of `Interlocked.CompareExchange<T>(ref T, T, T)` with something like `typeof(Interlocked).GetMethod(nameof(Interlocked.CompareExchange), 1, new Type[] { x, x, x})`

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus Do you mean you want the generic method definition? What about passing in some random type, and then calling `GetGenericMethodDefinition` on the method info you got?

Comment: @Sweeper That might work, am gonna test it and update the question if it works

Comment: You might want to edit your question, since you are now asking about something else (getting a generic method declaration).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution turns out to be quite simple:

```
Type genericType = Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0);
Type[] types = new Type[] { genericType.MakeByRefType(), genericType, genericType };

MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Interlocked).GetMethod(nameof(Interlocked.CompareExchange), 1, types);
```

Comment: Note that `Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter` is .NET Core 2.1+ and .NET Standard 2.1+ only

Comment: Thank you so much. I've looked all over for this solution and everyone always has some solution that uses "GetMethods"